# EXE with multiple embedded icons

Tags: delphi, icons, embedded-resource

I've made a VCL application in Delphi, and set the **application icon** using the Project/Options dialog. I also added **additional icons** to the application by adding an RC file to the project. None of these is named "MAINICON" in the RC file to avoid conflict with the application icon resource.

The EXE contains all icons: the application icon, and the additional icons listed in the RC file. When I start the EXE, both the main form and the taskbar button will display the application icon, as expected.

The **problem** is that file managers (Explorer, Total Commander etc.) display one of the additional icons for the exe. Why? Is it possible to make the application icon displayed in file managers?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that you're experiencing Windows caching your icons? Have you ever used that icon any time in the past?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848585/some-xe2-programs-dont-show-new-executable-icons-in-windows-explorer/19849327#19849327

Comment: As a test, move the EXE to a folder it's never been to before, run it, and see if you still have the wrong icon.

Comment: @JerryDodge I've already cleared the windows icon cache. It didn't help.

Comment: @JerryDodge If I create a shortcut to the EXE, and I open the Properties/Change Icon dialog, it shows every icon. The one icon shown first in the list is the one shown by Explorer. The one I've added as the application icon comes later in the list. Is it possible that file managers choose the *first* embedded icon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK Windows selects the first icon resource, in alphabetical order. So rename your addidional icon resources so that they come after `MAINICON` in the alphabetical order. Rebuild and clear the icon cashe to see does it fix it.

Comment: This helped :) To make sure "MAINICON" comes first, I started the name of other icon resources with "MAINICON_". Actually they are copies of the main icon with different background colors, so this don't even make the naming illogical. Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: Are you sure that this is true? I think the shell uses the first icon that it finds. It just so happens that Delphi sorts the icons by name when creating the res file. Or am I remembering wrong? Have you found any docs? It kind of sucks that Delphi hard codes `MAINICON` and means that you cannot give icons names that are less than `MAINICON`.

Comment: I'm with David here.  But easy to check : take CFF Explorer or Re stacker or anything  open the EXE and rename icons without reordering them and check the outcome.

Comment: David, youre probably correct that the shell takes the first icon and that Delphi is sorting them alphabetically when creating resources in binary. I just remember that when I had similar problem the solution was to rename other icons so that they come after `mainicon` in alphabetical order.

Comment: This is documented as *"Windows chooses the icon with the numerically lowest identifier"*. See the chapter *"Choosing an Icon"* in [`this article`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx).

Comment: If anyone is interested, I ended up using only one icon, namely the MAINICON, and generate the others from this one when the application starts. In spite of this, thanks everyone for the help!