# change system tray icon (quicklaunchicon) Launch4j, Inno setup

Tags: inno-setup, launch4j

I have created the exe file from jar and used this exe to create the installer using Inno setup. However when I install the system tray icon is not changing to custom icon I am proving in the .iss script. With Inno Setup the application icon which is displayed in Start > Program Files is picked up correctly but not the system tray icon.

I used the resource hacker to verify that the exe file has the image which needs to be displayed in the system tray.  When Installing I do get prompted to select the desktop icon and quicklaunch icon. Desktop icon is picked correctly but not the quicklaunch icon.

Could some one suggest how to customize the system tray icon (quicklaunchicon).

Comment: First of all, this is not the system tray. Second of all, it sounds like you're experiencing the common pains of Windows caching your icons. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848585/some-xe2-programs-dont-show-new-executable-icons-in-windows-explorer/19849327#19849327

Comment: @Jerry, icon cache is being refreshed by Inno Setup.

Comment: @JerryDodge I tried your suggested, it did not work...Also started the .exe file from a different folder still the same issue. Any other clues please ?

Comment: Does your debug log show anything about your icons?

Comment: @JerryDodge how do I find the debug log ?

Comment: When you run your installer from the IDE in debug mode, it's on the very bottom of the window.

Comment: What would log show about icons other than what you can see in the script ?

Comment: @TLama No idea, but it can provide some hints on what's included/compressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JerryDodge Thank you for the clues. The jar itself had the icon file which needed to be replaced. After replacing it, everything worked.