# can not change Delphi application icon

Tags: delphi

I change the icon in 'Project Option'-'Application'
but it does not work

so I change line in project file as

{$R *.res} to {$R .res}

but it does not work neither.

Your comment welcome

Comment: Sometimes Windows caches icons. Try refreshing the folder or copying executable to some other folder.

Comment: What Delphi version? What platform? If it's the icon cache thing, look at http://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-the-icon-cache-windows

Comment: Your icon has been cached. Restart the machine. Changed back to {$R *.res}

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848585/some-xe2-programs-dont-show-new-executable-icons-in-windows-explorer/19849327#19849327

Answer (score 1):

About which icon are you talking about?

If this is the icon of executable file then it is posible that the old icon was chached by windows. If you are on windows Vista and newer pressing F5 inside the explorer window will refresh all icons from all files in that forlder. On Windows XP you might be forced to log off and relog for the file incon to be reloaded.

But if you are talking about icon that is shown on title bar of your application or on taskbar button then it truely means that Delphi isn't updating the resource file corectly. 
Or perhaps you have added another resource file from which icon is tried to be read from. In this case make sure that resource files are compiled in correct order.